# Como paso los datos de una tabla a String en asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

soy nuevo en el mundo de asp.net, tengo una lista de datos en mi variable dato, que obtengo de mi base de datos pero no puedo pasar los valores a texto, este es mi codigo:

```
dato = lbl.ObtenerDatos(usu, contra, pError)
            Session("cedula") = dato.Rows(0).ToString
```

No me da error, pero cuando lo imprimo en pantalla sale esto: "System.Data.DataRow"

Comment: El problema que tiene es que esta convirtiendo a String toda la instancia de DataRow (normalmente las clases en .Net que no tienen una implementación propia del método ToString() devuelven una cadena que representa el nombre de la clase en este caso "System.Data.DataRow"). Para obtener un dato especifico de la fila debe indicar el nombre de campo de la fila o el subindice: Es decir `Sesion("cedula") = dato.Rows(0).item("AquiElNombreDelCampo").ToString()`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Mauricio Ortega, me funciono perfectamente, gracias por el dato y la explicación. No se como darte el voto positivo pero gracias.